# Trying to integrate automatic login to forum (phpbb3)

Tags: php, phpbb3

I m using phpbb 3.0.12 and php 5.4.28.

I have a site in which I use phpbb as a forum. Lately I wanted to integrate the login procedures so I wouldn't need to login twice.

To do this (and to make it look better) I decide to place the forum itself in a . I ran into a few problems with this so in the end I decided that instead of place the forum index.php in the iframe I wrapped the whole thing in a file called wrap.php. This worked better but not fully.

I did a small change on the index.php in phpbb which I mainly check if IN_PHPBB is defined and if it is then it skips the login process:

```
if (!defined("IN_PHPBB"))
{
    define('IN_PHPBB', true);
    $phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : './';
    $phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
    include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
    include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_display.' . $phpEx);

    // Start session management
    $user->session_begin();
    $auth->acl($user->data);
    $user->setup('viewforum');
}
```

My wrap.php looks like this:

```
<?php
$username = $_GET['name'];
$password = '';

// phpBB inclusion protection
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : './';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);

if (!isset($_GET['f']))
{
    // Start session management
    $user->session_begin();
    $auth->acl($user->data);

    // login to forum
    $result = $auth->login($username, $password, 1);

    include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_display.' . $phpEx);
    $user->setup('viewforum');

    include('index.php');
}
else
{
    $user->session_begin();
    $auth->acl($user->data);

    // login to forum
    $result = $auth->login($username, $password, 1);

    include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_display.' . $phpEx);
    include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/bbcode.' . $phpEx);

    include('viewtopic.php');
}

?>
```

The $_GET['f'] and $_GET['t'] is sent in the wrap if I am to go to a specific topic.

Ok... the symptoms. Well for starters on IE... I come to an empty page. If I click on board index I am taken there without problem logged in. Why? And are there a way to tell it to go directly to board index?

On Chrome it doesn't work at all, it doesn't even login for some reason. So I guess that has something to do with that the cookies aren't set correctly.

If I go to a specific topic - on IE it just claims I am not allowed to view that topic, I click on board index and then I can move through the forum and get there no problem.

On Chrome the same thing as before, since I am not logged in I get a message stating I am not authorized. Clicking on board index puts me at the login page.